# Cartesian power (cartesian product with self arbitrary times)

Tags: ruby, cartesian-product

I have a need in my code to calculate the cartesian product of an array with itself a varying number of times. For example, if my array is `[1,2]` and I need to fill these values into three slots, the result would be:

```
[1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,2,1]
[1,2,2]
[2,1,1]
[2,1,2]
[2,2,1]
[2,2,2]
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for permutation with repetition and Ruby's `Array` from standard library luckily [implements this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation):

```
[1,2].repeated_permutation(3).to_a
# [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I had not seen this previously.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variant of your answer:

```
class Array
  def **(n)
    product( *([self]*(n-1)) )
  end
end

[1,2]**3
  # => [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2],
  #     [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Ah, I like that far more than `.times.map`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because I like monkeypatching, I put this on the array itself:

```
class Array
  def **(n)
    self.product( *(n-1).times.map{ self } )
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if there's a more elegant way to pass *n-1* copies of yourself to the method, though.